# How to import file for TypeScript definition file

Tags: typescript, react-toolbox

I am trying to update the TypeScript definition file for react-toolbox found [here](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/react-toolbox.d.ts)

I have fixed a number of compile errors and now I have:

> ERROR in /myproject/typings/main/definitions/react-toolbox/index.d.ts
>   (1047,8): error TS2664: Invalid module name in augmentation, module
>   'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar' cannot be found.

relating to the following code in the `definition file`:

```
declare module 'react-toolbox' {
    import AppBar from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar';
```

I have installed the definition file using typings and my `typings.json` file includes:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-toolbox": "npm:react-toolbox",
```

I am using the npm install method because in my tsconfig.json I use exclude and it is not found automatically:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
],
```

`tsconfig.json` uses "node" module resolution

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
```

I'm not sure if I've incorrectly configured the consuming project to be able to find the files in node_modules, or the TypeScript definition file needs to be modified to conform to a standard way of achieving this. I would like to achieve this in the standard way so I can make a pull request and have it updated.

Are all these module declarations even needed, or could it be simplified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was related to using npm link and webpack. I have unlinked react-toolbox and overwrote the version in the Typings directory with my own and it seems to work.

I have also found [this link](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/396), which I will try later to see if I can get npm link working again.

Comment: could you please explain more what you've done to solve this?

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko It was a while ago, so I don't recall specifically. I probably used `npm unlink` or deleted the node modules and reinstalled.